# Unhandled Exception: Please provide ShowCaseView context

Tags: flutter

Implementing showcaseview in Flutter raises this error and I can't figure out where it's coming from. The code shown below is part of my project:

```
BuildContext myContext;
  
  initState(){
  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
  Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 400), () {
    ShowCaseWidget.of(myContext).startShowCase([_timeline_filter]);
  
  });
});
super.initState();
  }
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken the variable myContext doesn’t hold any value

Comment: Using the default context still produces the same error

Comment: You should have mentioned that showecasewidget comes from a plugin please try this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66077083/unhandled-exception-exception-please-provide-showcaseview-context-in-flutter

Comment: None of those solutions work unfortunately